# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError using a gallery with multitasking

Tags: java, android

when i run the pics.java class i get this error

```
11-07 20:23:15.468: E/AndroidRuntime(4294): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

This is my pics.java class:

```
package kostas.menu.climb;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.PointF;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.FloatMath;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class therisospics extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

   public Context cont;

    private static final String TAG = "Touch";
       // These matrices will be used to move and zoom image
       Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
       Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();

       // We can be in one of these 3 states
       static final int NONE = 0;
       static final int DRAG = 1;
       static final int ZOOM = 2;
       int mode = NONE;

       // Remember some things for zooming
       PointF start = new PointF();
       PointF mid = new PointF();
       float oldDist = 1f;

       private Gallery gallery;

       private Integer[] Imgid = {
                R.drawable.kosm1,R.drawable.th2,R.drawable.th3,R.drawable.th4,R.drawable.th5,R.drawable.th6,R.drawable.th7,R.drawable.th8,R.drawable.th9,R.drawable.th10};


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gallery);

       final ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        view.setImageResource(Imgid[0]);



         gallery = (Gallery) findViewById(R.id.examplegallery);
         gallery.setAdapter(new AddImgAdp(this));

         gallery.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                view.setImageResource(Imgid[position]); 
            }
        });
    } 


    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
          ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

       // Dump touch event to log
       dumpEvent(event);

    // Handle touch events here...
       switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
          savedMatrix.set(matrix);
          start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
          Log.d(TAG, "mode=DRAG");
          mode = DRAG;
          break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
          oldDist = spacing(event);
          Log.d(TAG, "oldDist=" + oldDist);
          if (oldDist > 10f) {
             savedMatrix.set(matrix);
             midPoint(mid, event);
             mode = ZOOM;
             Log.d(TAG, "mode=ZOOM");
          }
          break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
          mode = NONE;
          Log.d(TAG, "mode=NONE");
          break;
       case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
          if (mode == DRAG) {
             // ...
             matrix.set(savedMatrix);
             matrix.postTranslate(event.getX() - start.x,
                   event.getY() - start.y);
          }
          else if (mode == ZOOM) {
             float newDist = spacing(event);
             Log.d(TAG, "newDist=" + newDist);
             if (newDist > 10f) {
                matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
             }
          }
          break;
       }

       view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
       return true; // indicate event was handled
    }


    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
           float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
           float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
           return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
        }

    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
           float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
           float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
           point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
        }


    private void dumpEvent(MotionEvent event) {
           String names[] = { "DOWN" , "UP" , "MOVE" , "CANCEL" , "OUTSIDE" ,
              "POINTER_DOWN" , "POINTER_UP" , "7?" , "8?" , "9?" };
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           int action = event.getAction();
           int actionCode = action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
           sb.append("event ACTION_" ).append(names[actionCode]);
           if (actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN
                 || actionCode == MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP) {
              sb.append("(pid " ).append(
              action >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_ID_SHIFT);
              sb.append(")" );
           }
           sb.append("[" );
           for (int i = 0; i < event.getPointerCount(); i++) {
              sb.append("#" ).append(i);
              sb.append("(pid " ).append(event.getPointerId(i));
              sb.append(")=" ).append((int) event.getX(i));
              sb.append("," ).append((int) event.getY(i));
              if (i + 1 < event.getPointerCount())
                 sb.append(";" );
           }
           sb.append("]" );
           Log.d(TAG, sb.toString());
        }
    public class AddImgAdp extends BaseAdapter {
        int GalItemBg;
        private Context cont;

        public AddImgAdp(Context c) {  
            cont = c;
            TypedArray typArray = c.obtainStyledAttributes(R.styleable.Gallery1);
            GalItemBg = typArray.getResourceId(R.styleable.Gallery1_android_galleryItemBackground, 0);
            typArray.recycle();
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return Imgid.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ImageView imgView = new ImageView(cont);

            imgView.setImageResource(Imgid[position]);
            imgView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(80, 70));
            imgView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_XY);
            imgView.setBackgroundResource(GalItemBg);

            return imgView;
        }
    }

}
```

How could i setImageBitmap(null) ?
Could that be a solution?thanks

P.S.:My drawable folder is about 2 mb

Answer (score 1):

Your drawable folder may be 2MB, but once those images are uncompressed, they're going to take up a lot more memory. You should make sure that your images are scaled to an appropriate size for the device instead of scaling them on display.

Comment: My images size is 700*460...is that ok or i have to get them in a smaller size?